# Best way to divide up a nav?

Tags: css, less

I have a nav that looks like this:

---

nav 1 | nav 2 | nav 3

---

There is a top and bottom border and each li has a border right to get the pipe.

When you hover over each nav item, the item turns black, the problem is the pipe, when you hover over the middle or right nav item, the pipe from the previous item sticks out, because there is padding around it's parent. This padding is required in the design.

What's the best way around this?

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="span4">
    <a href="/">
              <span class="inner">Nav 1</span>
            </a>
        </li>
 //etc...
```

CSS:

```
li {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;

   a {
      padding: 5px 0;
      &:hover {             
         color: white;
         background-color: black;
      }
      .inner{
         border-right: 2px solid black;
      } 

   }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v27DS/21/)

Comment: Is this CSS LESS or SASS ? Please specify it also.

Comment: the only element that changes the box size while you're hovering the link is a right border. The padding is still there even on normal state

Comment: JSfiddle required.

Comment: did you try adding `box-sizing: border-box` on the .inner span element?

Answer (score 1):

Without a JSfiddle, I can't be sure, but if you've styled the list items as `inline-block` elements, there is a weird little quirk where line breaks in your HTML markup will create spaces between consecutive `inline-block` elements.

Have a look at this CSS-Tricks post http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ that has a couple suggestions on how to remove the spaces.

---

**UPDATED:** I've [forked your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yetti/LdKfG/4/) and made these changes so the border no longer sticks out:

Added a left border to the `.inner` selector.

```
.inner {
    ...
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

This simulates the right border of the previous element which gets covered up by the -2px left margin on the `a` selector:

```
a {
    ...
    margin-left: -2px;
    ...
}
```

This negative margin aligns the left border with the previous list item's right border, so both borders should appear like they're inside the `a` element.

The above changes add a left border and padding to the first list element, so I've negated the effects by adding a `first` class to the first list item and removing the -2px left margin and the left border with the following selectors:

```
.first a {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.first .inner {
    border-left: none;
}
```

The hover background color change is just to show what's happening a bit better, since it's a bit hard to see against a black background.